# WPF Setting Content for Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF app I have several labels on multiple pages that all look the same but may change style during program running (all at once).

After much searching online, I have gone through Window.Resources templates and User Controls (neither great for styling when changes are possible during program run) and have currently settled on CustomControl. However, I can't figure out how to set its Content. Some labels will have a wrap panel with mutiple grandchildren and some will just have text. However, I cannot work it out either way. This seems to be a program beyond Label. What am I missing?

My Control (just changed to inherit from Label):

```
 public class MyControl : Label
    {
        static MyControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
        }
    }
```

No changes to Themes.Generic.xaml

My Window XAML (styling here for testing purposes):

```
<local:MyControl Height="100">
            <TextBlock Text="hi there" FontSize="60"></TextBlock>
            <!-- More children will be needed, but lets start with one for now -->
</local:MyControl>

<local:MyControl Height="100" Content="this should exist" FontSize="50" />
```

How do I get that content to show up?

Edit: Removing the DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a default template for your custom control if you're to override its `DefaultStyleKeyProperty`, in your `Themes/Generic.xaml`. Base it on the default template of `Label`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}"/>
```

Alternatively, you can remove the overriding of the `DefaultStyleKeyProperty` and leave your control like this:

```cs
public class MyControl : Label
{
    // No overriding
}
```